# Splitting LINQ query based on predicate

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like a method that would split an `IEnumerable` at a predicate, grouping items together by their index relative to the predicate. For example, it could split a `List<string>` at items satisfying `x => MyRegex.Match(x).Success`, with items "in between" such matches being grouped together.

Its signature could look something line

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
    int bool count
)
```

, possibly with an extra element of the output containing all of the dividers.

Is there a more efficient and/or compact way to implement this than a `foreach` loop? I feel like it should be possible to implement with LINQ methods, but I can't put my finger on it.

**Example:**

```
string[] arr = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Nine", "Four", "Seven", "Five"};
arr.Split(x => x.EndsWith("e"));
```

Either of the following would be OK:

```
IEnumerable<string> {{}, {"Two"}, {}, {"Four", "Seven"}, {}}
IEnumerable<string> {{"Two"}, {"Four", "Seven"}}
```

the optional element for storing matches would be `{"One", "Three", "Nine",  "Five"}`.

Comment: You mean something other than `group by`?

Comment: What do you mean by "split"?  Return two lists, one that matches and one that doesn't?

Comment: Yes - it would split not based on characteristics of the items, but based on positioning.

Comment: @Arithmomaniac, you mean something like `Skip()` and `Take()`?

Comment: I am a bit confused. How is this different from `Where()`?

Comment: @Tyrsius, `Where()` filters, it does not group or "split".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi He is asking for it to return a list based on a predicate, right?

Comment: @Tyrsius, it looks like he wants to group items depending on the result of a predicate, but a further comment says `based on positioning`, so it might be more complicated than that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning what makes good examples.

Comment: Could you write the foreach loop that does what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do this through an extension method (this method assumes you ignore the partitioned item):

```
/// <summary>Splits an enumeration based on a predicate.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method drops partitioning elements.
/// </remarks>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> partitionBy,
    bool removeEmptyEntries = false,
    int count = -1)
{
    int yielded = 0;
    var items = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!partitionBy(item))
            items.Add(item);
        else if (!removeEmptyEntries || items.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return items.ToArray();
            items.Clear();

            if (count > 0 && ++yielded == count) yield break;
        }
    }

    if (items.Count > 0) yield return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I *think* this will return empty interstitial arrays if there are two or more consecutive items that satisfy `partitionBy()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yeah his example includes the empty guys in between.

Comment: @sixlettervariables the thinking was that it would only do that at the edges, if the first and/or last items were matches. They could be blank, too, if that makes implementation easier.

Comment: @Arithmomaniac: You could easily modify this algorithm to handle that situation. I've instead chosen to model it after `String.Split`. *When in Rome!*

Comment: You could continue to model `string.split` and provide an overload that determines whether or not to include empty values.  It's easy enough to check if the list is empty and not `yield return` it when that setting is active.

Comment: The problem with this approach and Servy's is that it uses an inner List<> to gather each set of items. The repercussions are that you can't lazily evaluate the inner groups. If you want to take the first value out of the sequence, it will still evaluate the whole first inner group. And if the sequence is an infinite repeat of "one", you'll never get any values out of Split, and you'll get an OutOfMemoryException as the list fills up. I tried rewriting this approach to use lazy evaluation but wasn't successful, though I could get it working with with an Observable.

Comment: @NiallConnaughton: I'm not sure you can rewrite it with a standard deferred evaluation approach. I would imagine in a scheme where you're partitioning an input set, you wouldn't be asking questions about the first (or N-th) item of the first partition. You would use `TakeWhile` in those cases.

Comment: It depends how generic you want this to be, I suppose. If your sequence is expensive to generate, or has side effects to generate, then you don't want to enumerate more than you need. Eg if it was a sequence of prime numbers, depending on your predicate, you might be evaluating hundreds of prime numbers the consumer doesn't care about, just to get the values it needs. Obviously the solution here works, I just prefer to find solutions that don't show observable signs of statefulness. Which is tricky in this case.

Answer (score 45):

If you're looking to avoid the extension method, you could always use:

```
var arr = new[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Nine", "Four", "Seven", "Five"};

var result = arr.ToLookup(x => x.EndsWith("e"));

// result[true]  == One Three Nine Five
// result[false] == Two Four Seven
```

Comment: This is a neat trick but does not keep the true items grouped by split.

Comment: It's a good solution. Also, we can name the variable in positive words. In Andy's example, name the varaible as `itemsEndWithE`, so `itemsEndWithE[false]` means items don't end with E. We don't need additional variables representing that.

Comment: It's a good solution, albeit to a different question. the question that this title sounds like, not the question asked.

Comment: Bonus point because the LookUp allows empty input and empty outputs.

Comment: You can make it into a tuple (that you can deconstruct) by doing: `var (good, bad) = arr.ToLookup(x => x.EndsWith("e")) switch { var result => (result[true], result[false]) };`. Extension method: `public static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>) Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, bool> predicate) => seq.ToLookup(predicate) switch { var lookup => (lookup[true], lookup[false]) };`

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    List<TSource> group = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return group.AsEnumerable();
            group = new List<TSource>();
        }
        else
        {
            group.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return group.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to call `AsEnumerable` on the list here?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Partition<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    yield return source.Where(predicate);
    yield return source.Where(x => !predicate(x));
}
```

Example:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var parts = list.Partition(x => x % 2 == 0);
var even = parts.ElementAt(0); // contains 2, 4
var odd = parts.ElementAt(1); // contains 1, 3, 5
```

Comment: This solution is not great for performance, you'll be iterating the list twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would partition a source collection using the provided key selector. This way, you could also slice complex objects based on simple properties.

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Slice<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> selector,
        Func<TKey, TKey, bool> partition)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
        if (partition == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(partition));

        var seed = new List<List<TSource>> { new List<TSource>() };

        return source.Aggregate(seed, (slices, current) => 
        {
            var slice = slices.Last();
            if (slice.Any())
            {
                var previous = slice.Last();
                if (partition(selector(previous), selector(current)))
                {
                    slice = new List<TSource>();
                    slices.Add(slice);
                }
            }
            slice.Add(current);
            return slices;

        }).Select(x => x.AsReadOnly());
    }
}
```

A trivial example:

```
// slice when the difference between two adjacent elements is bigger than 5
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 20 };
var output = input.Slice(i => i, (x, y) => y - x > 5);
```