# Select items between two other items using LINQ

Tags: linq, collections, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary collection from a single collection below the key in the dictionary is every file of type "k" and the values for each key are files of type "a". In other words, I'm trying to build a parent-child relationship but the file names are unique and do not denote the relationship between "a" and "k" file types. The only relationship is the file date. For example, file 4 will be a key b/c it's of type "k" and it's values will be files 3 and 2 because their file date is greater than file 3's date. file 1 should not be included as a child of file 4 since it's of type "k" even though it's date is greater than file 3.

Single Collection to work with:

```
IEnumerable<IFile>

file name   file type   file date
file1       k           2013-01-01
file2       a           2012-03-30
file3       a           2012-02-27
file4       k           2012-02-23
file5       a           2011-03-31
file6       k           2011-02-24
file7       a           2010-08-24
file8       a           2010-03-31
file9       k           2010-02-26
```

Desired output:

```
Dictionary<IFile, IEnumerable<IFile>>

key     value
file1   none b/c no files of type "a" exist with a date greater than file1
file4   file3, file2
file6   file5
file9   file8, file7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var result = data.Where(x => x.Type == 'k')
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name,
                               x => data.Where(a => a.Type == 'a' &&
                                               a.Date >= x.Date)
                                        .Select(a => a.Name)
                                        .ToList());
```

That wouldn't *quite* get what you want though - because the entry for 2010-02-26 would include *all* of the future ones. So it's not just a case of this relationship:

> For example, file 4 will be a key b/c it's of type "k" and it's values will be files 3 and 2 because their file date is greater than file 3's date.

It sounds like it's actually:

> For example, file 4 will be a key b/c it's of type "k" and it's values will be files 3 and 2 because their file date is greater than file 3's date *and their file date is less than file 1's date*.

That's going to be trickier. You might want something like:

```
var orderedKeys = data.Where(x => x.Type == 'k')
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                      .Concat(null); // You'll see why in a minute...

// Just for convenience. Could make this more efficient, admittedly.
var values = data.Where(x => x.Type == 'a').ToList();

var result = orderedKeys.Zip(orderedKeys.Skip(1),
                             (current, next) => new { current, next })
                        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.current.Name,
     // Sorry for the formatting...
     pair => values.Where(v => v.Date >= pair.current.Date &&
                               pair.next == null || v.Date < pair.next.Date)
                   .Select(v => v.Name)
                   .ToList());
```

That's if you want to be *really* LINQ-y. It would be more efficient to walk through both keys and values ordered by date though:

```
var ordered = data.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
var result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var currentList = null;
foreach (var item in ordered)
{
    if (item.Type == 'a' && currentList != null)
    {
        currentList.Add(item.Name);
    }
    else if (item.Type == 'k')
    {
        currentList = new List<string>();
        result[item.Name] = currentList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and detailed comment. I know my question specified LINQ but that was based on thinking there was no other way to do this. The other answers posted are viable but the simplicity of iterating through the keys and values works well for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple LINQ-based solution (pretty concise without all my comments):

```
// first, get the key files in order by date
var orderedKeys = files.Where(f => f.Type == 'k')
   .OrderBy(f => f.Date)
    // since I'm going to be enumerating this multiple times, call ToList() so we only
    // do the sort and filter once (if you don't care you could just inline this below)
    .ToList();

// start with all files of type 'a'
var dict = files.Where(f => f.Type == 'a')
    // group the 'a' files by the last key file whose date is <= the date of the 'a'
    // file. Since we've sorted the key files, this should be the correct parent for a
    .GroupBy(f => orderedKeys.Where(key => key.Type == 'k').Last(key => key.Date <= f.Date))
    // finally, convert the groups to a Dictionary
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g);
```

Note that this is somewhat inefficient because it loops over the orderedKeys enumerable for each 'a' file (the conciseness is probably worth it though if the files list is not too large). To avoid this, you could use a non-LINQ iterative solution where you start by sorting the entire files list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split` extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438442/480799) to get the items for each key.  You can then `Zip` the keys with the items and convert the sequence to a `Dictionary`.

```
var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(f => f.Date).ToArray();
var keys = orderedFiles.Where(f => f.Type == 'k');
// Call Skip(1) to skip the items that are before any keys.
var itemGroups = orderedFiles.Split(f => f.Type == 'k').Skip(1);
var result = keys.Zip(itemGroups, (key, items) => new { key, items })
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.items);
```

Here is the extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    List<TSource> group = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return group.AsEnumerable();
            group = new List<TSource>();
        }
        else
        {
            group.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return group.AsEnumerable();
}
```