# What is the most efficient way to split a List into two Lists based on one condition?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I want to split a list into two seperate lists one with elements which fulfil the condition and another with elements that don't fulfil the condition.
A possible Solution would be this:

```
var listTrue = list.Where(x => x.condition());
var listFalse = list.Where(x => !x.condition());
```

But i am not just looking for a solution. I am looking for an efficient solution. I don't demand any performance metrics.
I would be happy to receive ideas and solutions. I would benchmark those and look if any of them make a significant performance gain.
I am also looking for a solution that is available in the .net framework 4.8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438235/splitting-linq-query-based-on-predicate/31071355 check this out

Comment: In short use ToLookup method

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient in terms of performance would be to do a `foreach` loop which will do it by `O(n)` complexity. Although I would recommend just using LINQ as you mentioned which will be `O(2n) = O(n)`. If your list contains lots of rows and you really need the performance to be most efficient, go for it:

```
 var listTrue = new List<...>();
 var listFalse = new List<...>();

 foreach (var item in list)
 {
     if (item.condition())
     {
         listTrue.Add(item);
     }
     else
     {
         listFalse.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

Note, you might do it in parallel also if it is logically make sense.

Comment: Technically they both have an `O(n)` (linear) complexity, but you are correct to say that the LINQ version would require 2 iterations.

Comment: A basic for, if it is available on the manipulated collection, which is the case for Lists, will be a little more optimized. Perhaps AddRange with preallocated arrays too (written without considering that at the time).

Comment: `O(2n) == O(n)`

Comment: For n smaller than 2¹⁶ a `for` loop is more efficient by 4% and for 2¹⁶ - 2³⁰ it's more efficient to access the private backing field for the list, load it into a contiguous block of memory and use a for loop to iterate.